# How can I find tsmc65N (or 65nm feature size) NMOS parameters definition in Cadence Virtuoso?

Tags: cmos, cadence, virtuoso, parameters

How can I find tsmc65N (or 65nm feature size) NMOS parameters definition in Cadence Virtuoso? They are all abbreviated and there is not any guide there.

For example, I want to know the value of "process transconductance parameter" or "kn". in "results>print>model parameter", I can find "ptp". Is that the same as "process transconductance parameter"? Its value is 400u.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transistor appears to be modeled by a BSIM model, based on the fact that you're using tsmcN65 and you have a parameter `ptp`.

You can find a synopsis of the BSIM parameters in the official Cadence documentation at `MMSim->Virtuoso Simulator Components and Device Models Reference`, or locate another equivalent source for this reference. I don't know of an authorized public copy of this reference document, other than the one you access through the help files of your licensed Virtuoso/MMSim installation.

If you do not have access to it, then there's a non-Cadence document on the public Internet [here](https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5908900) that also discusses BSIM (as implemented in ADS). It mentions that ptp isn't what you're looking for:

> `Ptp` Vjsw linear temperature coefficient,    1/°C, [default value]   0

The BSM model doesn't include a "process transconductance parameter" to my knowledge, because it is *not* a simple `Id = k' W/L (Vgs-Vth)^2` model where you expect a "process transconductance parameter" of k.

If you want to estimate some sort of equivalent parameter, you can do so at *some operating point of interest* by simulating for the drain current and solving the rearranged equation

$$k' = \frac{L}{W}\frac{I_d}{(V_{gs}-V_{th})^2}$$

However, you should not expect there to be one single value for k' and I would find it hard to justify doing this calculation. The calculated value of k' will vary based on the operating point, for the simple reason that BSIM is a more accurate model than the square-law model, with many more parameters modelling all kinds of phenomena that affect the drain current.

Chances are, k' will vary significantly as your operating point moves around away from moderate inversion, e.g. likely increasing or becoming undefined/nonsensical in [subthreshold conduction/weak inversion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518887/why-is-the-transfer-curve-of-a-real-mos-not-perfectly-quadratical/518889#518889).

Comment: Thank you @nanofarad, well that is perfect but here we see that Vdsat is different from Vov. So is there any better approximation.

Comment: @mohammadrezza If you're asking for a closed-form approximation to BSIM by hand, then no, I don't have that.